# How is a failed login attempt represented with SAML with SP-initiated SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I would like to set up my Service Provider (SP) for SP-initiated SSO.

When the user successfully logs in, I'm expecting the IdP to POST a SAML Assertion to my SP (is this called endpoint on my SP called an Assertion Consumer Service?).

What should I expect to happen when my SP and IdP are configured correctly but the user fails to authenticate – either with their primary credentials or MFA? Will the IdP POST a failure message to my SP?

If so, what is the conventional terminology for this payload? Is it still called a SAML Assertion but containing some kind of failure syntax differences or is it a totally different type of SAML payload, called something else? Do both success and failure payloads get sent to the same SP endpoint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you get back from the Identity Provider is *always* a SAML Response. If it's a successful response, you get an assertion. If it's a failed response, you get an error message passed from the IdP... And there's no real "standard" for those responses, other than the typical SAML message formatting.

[Section 3.5.6](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56779/sstc-saml-bindings-errata-2.0-wd-06.pdf#page=25) of the Binding spec describes the expectation for the POST profile. Each profile will provide for this, but as the SP, in most situations, you'll be using this binding.

Section [3.2.2 of Core](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56776/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-07.pdf#page=40) defines the StatusResponseType - effectively, the status code of response that should be sent in various situations, the status message and status detail. It should be noted that most IdPs will simply return the `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:AuthnFailed` status code, and then *maybe* some additional detail in the status message or detail fields... But you cannot count on more than the code.

And yes, responses will **always** go to the typical SAML protocol endpoint, no matter their status.

Comment: Thanks! What about logout? It seems that the SP is supposed to make a logout request to the IdP after which I'm not sure if they respond with a success/failure and if so if that would be to the same login/logout endpoint at my SP?

Comment: Most IdP software has an SSO endpoint that expects AuthnRequests and an SLO endpoint that expects LogoutRequests. SP software has an ACS endpoint, an assertion consumer service, expecting assertions...

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, are you saying the SP has a single endpoint for receiving assertions which could assert any of the following: 1. successful login, 2. failed login, 3. successful logout, 4. failed logout?

Comment: That is generally the case, yes.